# Next-Auth v4.0 adapter for Sanity.io

Tags: adapter, next-auth, sanity

I have tried to modify the existing adapter @ https://www.sanity.io/plugins/next-auth-sanity to be compatible with Next-Auth V4 to no avail.

As I have read that Next-Auth V4 introduces some breaking changes to all existing adapters.

Has anyone integrated Next-Auth with Sanity.io for the EmailProvider option successfully with a custom adapter?

This is a piece of code (from the current next-auth-sanity library) which I believe is having some issues with next-Auth V4.

```
import { Profile, Session } from 'next-auth';
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters';
import { User } from 'next-auth';
import { SanityClient } from '@sanity/client';

export default function SanityAdapter(SanityClient, options = {never, User & {
        id: string;
    }, Profile, Session}) {
    return {
    }
}
```

The adapter documentation from next-auth is quite basic @ [Next-Auth Adapter documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/creating-a-database-adapter)